# plotting orbital trajectories in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, differential-equations

How can I setup the three body problem in python?  How to I define the function to solve the ODEs?

The three equations are
`x'' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * x`,
`y'' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * y`, and
`z'' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * z`.

Written as 6 first order we have

`x' = x2`,

`y' = y2`,

`z' = z2`,

`x2' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * x`,

`y2' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * y`, and

`z2' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * z`

I also want to add in the path Plot o Earth's orbit and Mars which we can assume to be circular.
Earth is `149.6 * 10 ** 6` km from the sun and Mars `227.9 * 10 ** 6` km.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                             
#  This program solves the 3 Body Problem numerically and plots the trajectories      

import pylab
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace

mu = 132712000000  #gravitational parameter
r0 = [-149.6 * 10 ** 6, 0.0, 0.0]
v0 = [29.0, -5.0, 0.0]
dt = np.linspace(0.0, 86400 * 700, 5000)  # time is seconds
```

Comment: What in particular are you asking about?  People are probably going to be more likely to help if you have a more specific problem.

Comment: @askewchan I don't know how to enter 6 first order ODEs as a function since `integrate.odeint` will only take first order equations.

Comment: You can use `integrate.ode` to solve higher order equations.

Comment: @askewchan yes if you write them as first order.  But I don't know how to define the function after that.

Comment: See http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem for another example.

Comment: And btw, instead of `-149.6 * 10 ** 6` just write `-149.6e6` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've shown, you can write this as a system of six first-order ode's:

```
x' = x2
y' = y2
z' = z2
x2' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * x
y2' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * y
z2' = -mu / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * z
```

You can save this as a vector:

```
u = (x, y, z, x2, y2, z2)
```

and thus create a function that returns its derivative:

```
def deriv(u, t):
    n = -mu / np.sqrt(u[0]**2 + u[1]**2 + u[2]**2)
    return [u[3],      # u[0]' = u[3]
            u[4],      # u[1]' = u[4]
            u[5],      # u[2]' = u[5]
            u[0] * n,  # u[3]' = u[0] * n
            u[1] * n,  # u[4]' = u[1] * n
            u[2] * n]  # u[5]' = u[2] * n
```

Given an initial state `u0 = (x0, y0, z0, x20, y20, z20)`, and a variable for the times `t`, this can be fed into `scipy.integrate.odeint` as such:

```
u = odeint(deriv, u0, t)
```

where `u` will be the list as above.  Or you can unpack `u` from the start, and ignore the values for `x2`, `y2`, and `z2` (you must transpose the output first with `.T`)

```
x, y, z, _, _, _ = odeint(deriv, u0, t).T
```

Comment: @dustin You should probably try to ask as a separate question.

Comment: I am getting value error too many values to unpack (expected 6)

Comment: @Juanlu001 That was because I'd left out the `.T` at first.